Error compiling / building MongoDB 6.0.15 Alpine Linux 3.19 / -Winterference-size
I’ve been trying to compile MongoDB 6.0.15 for Alpine Linux 3.19, and it’s been quite challenging, largely due to the use of musl instead of libc.
Among the errors faced are:
In src/mongo/util/aligned.h:
code
src/mongo/util/aligned.h:135:77: warning: use of 'std::hardware_destructive_interference_size' [-Winterference-size]
  135 | using CacheAligned = Aligned<T, stdx::hardware_destructive_interference_size>;
Even when trying to pass the flags -mtune, -mcpu, or --param hardware_destructive_interference_size=64, the error still persists.

Another error that has been hindering me is when compiling src/mongo/util/dns_query_posix_imp.h, I am informed that ‘res_nclose’, ‘res_ninit’, and ‘res_nstatus’ are not referenced. I have checked the file, and it contains the include for resolv.h, which I also have in my system.
I tried
python3 buildscripts/scons.py DESTDIR=/usr/bin/mongod/ install-mongod CXXFLAGS="--param hardware_destructive_interference_size=64"

but
(mongodb-src-r6.0.15) mongodb:~/mongodb-src-r6.0.15# python3 buildscripts/scons.py DESTDIR=/usr/bin/mongod/ install-mongod CXXFLAGS="--param hardware_destructive_interference_size=64"
Checking required python packages...
Requirements list:
    Cheetah3<=3.2.6.post1
    PyYAML==5.3.1
    cryptography==2.3; platform_machine == "s390x" or platform_machine == "ppc64le"
    cryptography==36.0.2; platform_machine != "s390x" and platform_machine != "ppc64le"
    ninja>=1.10.0
    packaging<=21.3
    psutil<=5.8.0
    pymongo<4.0,>=3.9
    pypiwin32>=223; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version > "3"
    pywin32>=225; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version > "3"
    regex<=2021.11.10
    requests<=2.26.0,>=2.0.0
    requirements_parser<=0.3.1
    setuptools
    types-PyYAML~=6.0.5
Resolved to these distributions:
    certifi 2024.2.2
    cffi 1.16.0
    charset-normalizer 2.0.12
    cheetah3 3.2.6.post1
    cryptography 36.0.2
    idna 3.7
    ninja 1.11.1.1
    packaging 21.3
    psutil 5.8.0
    pycparser 2.22
    pymongo 3.13.0
    pyparsing 3.1.2
    pyyaml 5.3.1
    regex 2021.11.10
    requests 2.26.0
    requirements-parser 0.3.1
    setuptools 65.5.0
    types-pyyaml 6.0.12.20240311
    types-setuptools 57.4.18
    urllib3 1.26.18
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: running with args /root/mongodb-src-r6.0.15/bin/python3 buildscripts/scons.py DESTDIR=/usr/bin/mongod/ install-mongod CXXFLAGS=--param hardware_destructive_interference_size=64
scons version: 3.1.2
python version: 3 10 14 'final' 0
CC is gcc
gcc found in $PATH at /usr/bin/gcc
CXX is g++
g++ found in $PATH at /usr/bin/g++
Checking if C++ compiler "g++" is GCC... no
Checking if C++ compiler "g++" is clang... no
Couldn't identify the C++ compiler
See /root/mongodb-src-r6.0.15/build/scons/config.log for details


You will need to dig into the SConstruct and your environment to understand what the disconnect is. The build system is unable to compile a simple text file with gcc. Start here.
You can explicitly set your compiler path by setting CXX in your scons invocation if that ends up being the problem with your environment.
Check your gcc version as well.
